# Slow Response When IIS Doesn't Target Default wwwroot and Does Project Folder as the Root

Tags: sql, asp.net, iis

Is it possible that setting the IIS root to the same directory to the project root will cause a slow performance?

I have an ASP.NET Web Application that handles some SQL commands to GET/POST records on the local SQL database. Recently I have came up with an idea that I no longer have to start debugging each time to test the code by changing the root of IIS from the default (C:\inetpub\wwwroot) to the root of the web-application project folder.

However, after that, I have encountered a problem where some manipulation on the web GUI, especially which include POST requests get extremely slow. For example, adding a new document or rewriting an existing one on the database now take about a minute whereas they did less than 20 seconds. Also, it seems that repeating POST commands make themselves slower (restarting the computer reset the situation). So I guess some read/write process may leave garbage and it conflicts with other processes.

Could anyone suggest any core issue about this phenomenon? Also please let me kwno if my explanation isn't enough clear to show the problem.

Comment: If I understand correctly, I'm guessing your DLL has been compiled in debug mode, which is always slower. Try building your project in release mode (which will recompile the DLL in release mode). You won't be able to debug, but that's why you usually have a dev environment and a prod environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have encountered a problem where some manipulation >on the web GUI, especially which include POST requests >get extremely slow

Changing the root directory is very unlikely to cause this issue.Your application was already performing very slow(20 seconds also is slow).

So no  phenomenon in my opinion,You have to debug your application to find out where the delay is.To find out the root cause,you can use any profiler like [perfview](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2012/10/09/improving-your-apps-performance-with-perfview/) or a tool like [debugdiag](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chaun/2014/02/17/three-ways-to-automate-a-hang-dump-in-debugdiag-2-0/).

In case of debugdiag,choose the second option in the above link to capture a memory dump.Once you have a memory dump,simply double click the dump file and debugdiag will do an automated analysis and tell you where the problem is in your application code. E.g it can tell you your DB call is taking time .If you are not able to find,please post the analysis result updated with the question

Comment: Sorry for the delay in this reply. To be honest, the problem wouldn't be solved because of the develop environment that didn't allow me to use the softwares. Also, @Nick 's way didn't work for me. But I'll try this approach when I have the same problem in another project. Thanks.